# How to hide the navigation bar after the soft keyboard is closed in android studio?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, uinavigationbar

I am currently working on an Android app using Android Studio and I'm facing a persistent issue that I cannot seem to resolve. The problem arises when I open the soft keyboard while interacting with an "EditText" view. Upon opening the soft keyboard, the navigation bar pops up and fails to hide again after I close the keyboard.

I've tried several online solutions to address this issue. Initially, I used flags applied to the layout, but encountered a problem where the flags were cleared whenever the user opened the keyboard. To work around this, I implemented a global listener and even hardcoded a flag to track keyboard closures, but this proved ineffective on certain devices. I also tried calling the flags inside the onBackPressed method, but the problem persisted. More recently, I attempted using the WindowInsetsController, but unfortunately the issue still remains. Below is the code snippet of the method currently called inside the onCreate method of the activity to hide the assets:

```
public static void hideAssets(final Activity activity) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(activity.getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsControllerCompat = WindowCompat.getInsetsController
            (activity.getWindow(), activity.getWindow().getDecorView());

    windowInsetsControllerCompat.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    windowInsetsControllerCompat.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
}
```

These are the two themes of my app (one of them is for the splash/launch screen):

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default Theme of App -->
    <style name="Theme.Eleanor" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000F2E</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000F2E</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Theme for the Launch Screen -->
    <style name="Theme.Launch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000F2E</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000F2E</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Eleanor">
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ControlActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```